# Stacked Bar Graph (Percentage) with 50+ created dummy variables?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I am working in python and have a dataframe with 50+ created dummy variables. Now, I am trying to create a stacked bar chart (perc) to show what the item-mix is every month. This is the dataframe:

```
date       | dummy_var1 | dummy_var2 | .. | dummy_var50
2021-01-01 | 3          | 0          |    | 0
2021-02-01 | 1          | 0          |    | 0
```

I am looking to create a stacked percentage bar chart for each date. However, since I have 50+ columns and NOT all columns have values (i.e 0%), I want to remove columns for a given month with 0 and only display columns with a positive values and stack those.

What is the best approach? I searched plotly and seaborn but could not find anything that matched this use case.

Comment: This question is very confusing. You need to add a lot more information about what exactly is needed. Do you want to stack the dates or the dummy_vars? Is "dummy_var1" to be a meaningful name? When you say "percentage", how do you define 100%?  Can you organize your items into meaningful groups? Can you post your best-effort code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use this technique: [Compute row percentages in pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820659/compute-row-percentages-in-pandas-dataframe)
- it then becomes very simple use of **plotly express**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

S = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        **{"date": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", freq="MS", periods=12)},
        **{
            f"dummy_var{i+1}": np.random.choice(
                list(range(S)),
                12,
                p=[0.9 if i == 0 else 0.1 / (S - 1) for i in range(S)],
            )
            for i in range(50)
        },
    }
)

px.bar(
    df.set_index("date").pipe(lambda d: d.div(d.sum(axis=1), axis=0)).reset_index(),
    x="date",
    y=[c for c in df.columns if c != "date"],
).update_layout(xaxis={"dtick": "M1"}, yaxis={"tickformat":".2%"})
```

[image]